# How to sync new directory added in my local main directory repo to github

Tags: git, github, repository

Assuming i have local project called python in a directory called `python` in which there are 2 subfolders named `windows` and `linux`.

Up to this point, I succeeded to send the whole to my github repo that I named python_script. I can see the 2 subfolders `windows` and `linux` and the files they contain.

Now, i added a new folder named `mac` in my local directory project named `python`.

From there, i wanted to sync with my github by trying lot of command (add, push, pull, etc) but none works. It says that everything up to date, nothing to commit, etc...

And in my github, there are always the same 2 folders from the beginning of the project...

I am out of idea.
Any help would be welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to

```
git add --all
git commit -a
```

if can't please type this after print out

```
git status
```

please try command 'tree'

```
$ tree python
python
├── linux
│   └── linux.py
├── mac
└── windows
    └── windows.py
```

If 'mac' folder empty can't anything.

```
$ cd python
$ git add --all
$ git commit -a 
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: sorry It doesn't work. It says nothing to commit

Comment: @VenomCA folder "mac" isn't empty?

If empty, try make some file.

'Git' is tracking file not folder.

Comment: Ok, my bad. The folder was empty. Now that'is populated i've sinced with git add . and git commit and git push. Thank you for the support.

Comment: @VenomCA Good! happy hear that!